# Handle null value when using strict attribute type PDO::FETCH_CLASS

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to fetch all rows and set it into `Inventory` class. Here's my class and how I fetch it

```php
class Inventory {
  public int $id;
  public string $name;
  public string $type_of;
  public float $weight;
}


$query = "SELECT * FROM inventories";

$inventories = $this->db->prepare($query);
$inventories->execute();
$inventories = $inventories->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Inventory');
```

In DB, the `type_of` attribute is nullable. So, when I execute the code, it throws an error :

**Typed property Inventory::$type_of must be string, null used**

Is there any ways to ignore the null value and convert it to its type default value.

Example : `type_of` is string, when the value is null so it will change into an empty string. `weight` is float, then it will change into `0.0`.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible solutions, you could set `strict_types` (read more about [Strict Typing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.strict)) to `off` in `PHP` and you will no longer have the `TypeError` you are getting, or you could keep the `strict_types` setting as is and simply make the following change:

from

```
public string $type_of;
```

to

```
public ?string $type_of;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare class properties to be nullable and/or to have default values.

For example:

```
class Inventory 
{
    public int $id;
    public string $name;
    public ?string $type_of = null;
    public float $weight = 0;
}
```

You may find this [blog post](https://stitcher.io/blog/typed-properties-in-php-74) helpful.